# Shorter solution for the equation $\frac{a}{ax-1}+\frac{b}{bx-1}=a+b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I saw this question in a book and tried to solve it as a normal quadratic equation.

But it became too lengthy after multiplication , rearrangement etc.

So can anyone please provide a shorter solution for the given equation??

Equation is $$\frac{a}{ax-1}+\frac{b}{bx-1}=a+b$$

Comment: Can you provide details of its lengthiness? Without know what steps you consider long its hard to tell what method the book used.

Comment: I multiplied by (ax-1)(bx-1) both sides and then applied quadratic formula,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The given equation can be solved as $$\frac{a}{ax-1} +\frac{b}{bx-1} = a+b$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{a}{ax-1} -b = a- \frac{b}{bx-1}$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{a-abx+b}{ax-1} = \frac{abx-a-b}{bx-1}$$ $$\Rightarrow (a-abx+b)(bx-1) = -(a-abx+b)(ax-1)$$ $$\Rightarrow (a-abx+b)(bx-1) + (a-abx+b)(ax-1) = 0$$ $$\Rightarrow (a-abx+b)(bx+ax-2) =0$$ $$\Rightarrow a+b-abx =0 \mid bx+ax-2 = 0$$ $$\Rightarrow x=\frac{a+b}{ab} \mid x=\frac{2}{a+b}$$ provided $$ab \neq 0 \& a+b\neq 0$$where $\mid$ stands for "or". Hope it helps.

Comment: Now, this is a better solution!

Comment: Provided that $ab\neq0$ and $a+b\neq0$.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelHoppe. I have corrected it.

Comment: Note that if $a=b=0$ the original equation holds for every value of $x$ (from the factor $a+b-abx=0$) and the case $a=0, b \neq 0$ has a solution given by the factor $bx+ax-2=0$ i.e. $x=\frac 2b$.

Answer (score 1):

$a(bx-1) + b(ax-1) = 2abx - (a+b) = (a+b)(abx^2-(a+b)x+1)\implies ab(a+b)x^2-((a+b)^2+2ab)x+2(a+b)=0$. We can use quadratic formula at this point.

Comment: I think this is the solution that @ Atul Mishra calls "lengthy". Because he said that the solution he worked out was solved as a normal quadratic equation. that's a guess only.

Answer (score 1):

One trivial solution is

$$
\left \{
  \begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{a}} &= b \\
    \frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{b}} &= a \\
  \end{align*}
\right. \implies x=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$$

Using product of roots

$$x\left( \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} \right)=\frac{2}{ab} \implies x=\frac{2}{a+b}$$